# Displaying a certain key into a certain tab bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, uitabview

I'm new to objective-c programming so I'm not sure about the coding.

Basically, I have an NSDictionary called lessonDict containing all my lesson modules. The keys in my NSDictionary are the days of the lessons, like Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday...

I have a tabBarController in my TimetableDayViewController.

When I click on 'Mon' on my tabBarController, it's supposed to only display out the lessons that are only for Monday.

May I know how can this be done?

Thanks.

My XML sheet (timetable XML):

```
<Timetable>
 <Lesson Day="Thursday">
   <ModuleGroup>IT1103</ModuleGroup>
   <Time>0800-0850</Time>
   <moduleCode>IT2201</moduleCode>
   <lessonType>Lecture</lessonType>
   <location>Ltl3</location>
   <staffName>Evelyn</staffName>
 </Lesson>
 <Lesson Day="Wednesday">
   <ModuleGroup>IT1103</ModuleGroup>
   <Time>0900-0950</Time>
   <moduleCode>IT1204</moduleCode>
   <lessonType>Practical</lessonType>
   <location>L539</location>
   <staffName>Aaron</staffName>
 </Lesson>
 <Lesson Day="Wednesday">
   <ModuleGroup>IT1103</ModuleGroup>
   <Time>1010-1100</Time>
   <moduleCode>IT1204</moduleCode>
   <lessonType>Practical</lessonType>
   <location>L539</location>
   <staffName>Aaron</staffName>
 <Lesson Day="Friday">
    <ModuleGroup>IT1103</ModuleGroup>
    <Time>1110-1200</Time>
    <moduleCode>IT1210</moduleCode>
    <lessonType>Tutorial</lessonType>
    <location>L601</location>
    <staffName>Katherine</staffName>
 </Lesson>
</Timetable>
```

TimetableDayViewController.m

```
-(id)initWithDay:(NSString *)whatday
{
   NSLog (@"test %@", whatday);
    if (self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain])
    {
    NSLog (@"test");
    self.day = whatday;
    self.tabBarItem.title = self.day;

    NSMutableArray *mon = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *tue = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *wed = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *thu = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *fri = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i=0;i<(lessonList.count); i++)
    {
        mon = [lessonDict objectForKey:@"Monday"];
        tue = [lessonDict objectForKey:@"Tuesday"];
        wed = [lessonDict objectForKey:@"Wenesday"];
        thu = [lessonDict objectForKey:@"Thursday"];
        fri = [lessonDict objectForKey:@"Friday"];
    }

    if ([whatday isEqualToString:@"Mon"])
    {
        [lessonList addObjectsFromArray:mon];
    }
    if ([whatday isEqualToString:@"Tue"])
    {
        [lessonList addObjectsFromArray:tue];
    }
    if ([whatday isEqualToString:@"Wed"])
    {
        [lessonList addObjectsFromArray:wed];
    }
    if ([whatday isEqualToString:@"Thu"])
    {
        [lessonList addObjectsFromArray:thu];
    }
    if ([whatday isEqualToString:@"Fri"])
    {
        [lessonList addObjectsFromArray:fri];
    }
}
return self;
}
```

if my codes are like this, may I know what's wrong with my codes?

Comment: please post sample of json

Comment: But I'm using XML and not JSON. But thanks for your help. It's greatly appreciated.

Comment: Basically he means post some code so we can help you debug it.

Answer (score 0):

First extract that day's json from the `lessonDict`.

```
[lessonDict objectForKey@"Monday"];
```

Depending on the type of the lesson modules, use appropriate variable. Now use the obtained data.

Comment: Thank you, Srikar Appal. I shall try the codes first. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it helps to those that needs this question answered to. But I solved my question already.

I created another array called dayList to store what I want. dayList array will only store the modules for the particular day. I created a property for my dayList so it can be accessed easily in TimetableDayViewController.

So in my TimetableDayViewController.m

(in parserDidEndDocument method)

```
dayList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i = 0; i < (lessonList.count); i++)
{
    timetable *t = [lessonList objectAtIndex:i];

    NSLog(@"Module Group: %@, Time: %@, Module Code: %@, Lesson Type: %@, Location: %@, Staff Name: %@, Day: %@", t.moduleGroup, t.moduleTime, t.moduleName, t.moduleType, t.moduleRoom, t.moduleLec, t.lessonDay);

        if ([t.lessonDay isEqual: self.day])
    {
        [dayList addObject:t];
    }
}
```

So at the cellForRowAtIndexPath just call this, it should be able to display what you want.

```
timetable *t = [dayList objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
```